# How to verify if a vector is really recovered?

Tags: matlab, optimization, numeric, numerical-methods, linear-programming

In compressed sensing, how to verify if a vector is recovered or how could one plot the figures on recovery rate? since in numerical experiments, there is always a difference between the original vector and the vector produced by compressed algorithms.

Comment: You could create a sparse signal, sample it and using only the sampled values try to recover it. Compare the recovered signal and the sparse signal you began with. You can try several statistical measures such as the RMS error between the signals.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to confirm that your vector is actually recovered would be to

- keep one copy of the vector
- compress another copy
- decompress the compressed vector
- compare with the original

This could be useful to do when you are trying to design or select a lossless compression method.

However, if you are in the setting where you have a vector, need to compress it. Later decompress it and want to know whether there was any loss. Then there is no practical way to be sure. Fortunately, you can get some indications whether your new vector resembles the old one by storing and comparing some statistics.

Some statistics that may be interesting, depending on your vector:

- Length
- Moments (Mean, variance etc.)
- Number of positive values
- Highest, and lowest value
- Smallest nonzero difference between two values
- The exact value of every 10000th element
- ...
- Basically whatever really matters to you